# script to remove users from several autorized_keys

Tags: shell

First of all I've to say I know nothing about scripting, I'm used to object oriented programming, and this is a new whole world. So it would be great to get some assitance :)

The thing is that I have a txt file with some usernames, and another txt file with computer names.
Those computers have several homes, and the user kay could be in some, all or none.
I need to remove the users given by the txt file, from all the homes in all the computers.

This is what I've done so far, but I'm miserably failing to achieve it.

```
#!/bin/bash

#removes user's public keys from all the homes in all the computers
#users_to_remove.txt hand made list with usernames to remove
#hosts.txt static list with all the computers

for user in $(cat users_to_remove.txt) 
do
 for host in $(cat hosts.txt)
 do
 ssh -t $host hostname << EOF
  echo $(uname -a)
  for homes in $(getent passwd | cut -f1 -d:)
  do
   if grep $user /home/$homes/.ssh/authorized_keys >/dev/null 2>&1
   then
    echo $homes
    echo "gotcha"
    echo " "
     sed -i.backup "${user}d" $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
   fi
  done
 EOF
 done
done
```

My idea is to get the first user, then access the first computer, get the local homes from that computer and, if the entry exists for this user remove it.
Once it finishes with the homes for the first machine, then it goes to the second computer until the end of the hosts.txt file. At this point, it gets the second username and repeats the process.

I've also tried accessing first to the computer and then the users, but it is the same.

It is probably wrong in some many ways, but I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible, so I can fully understand the code.

Maybe I'm being too ambitious by trying an exercise like this with my current level, but now that I'm stuck, I would like to know how it has to be done. On my mind it seemed quite simple. It is just some for/while and an if statement.

Thanks.

Comment: Start by running your script through https://www.shellcheck.net/ and making any fixes it suggests (Assuming there's no false positives about variable expansion).

Comment: @shawn. Thanks. I had no idea there was such a tool.
Now the code reports no issues, so now all I've to do is test it and keep this site on my bookmarks.
Yet, I'll need to read again about the indention, because I'm seeing contradictory information on how it should be done. But I know it is just me not fully understanding the concept :(